# Finding Whatsapp key file on WP8

Tags: 8.0, whatsapp

A lot of guides exist on the internet to decrypt whatsapp message databases and backups on Android using the key that is easily found on that OS. However, I'm using WP8, and I am trying to find the Whatsapp key file. I have a full EMMC dump, so I can access all protected file areas. However, I just don't know where to look for the key file on Windows Phone 8.

Comment: eMMC dump of the memory card or the phone?